# How to draw the line for list element from the starting of div container?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

The live example http://jsfiddle.net/vro0om/yhvnh/

I am trying to draw the line separating 2 li elemts in nested ul. But the line takes the width  of the container ul and not the div containing the complete structure. In the mentioned example I have used nested ul but in my working using ng-repeat to obtain the same effect.

```
.unstyled {

    padding-left: 24px;

}
.titleSeperator
 {
   background: black ;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   height : 1px;
   width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yhvnh/1/ ?

Comment: @dfsq no not on the right but touching the left margin of the div

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an easier way to do what you want.

First, remove all your `.titleSeperator` divs. Then, use the following CSS code for the parent `ul`:

```
ul.lines {
    line-height: 1.4em;
    background: linear-gradient(white 95%, black 5%);
    background-size: 100% 1.4em;
    background-origin: content-box;
}
```

The new fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yhvnh/2/

Some explanations for the CSS:

- `line-gradient` allows to create a gradient starting with 95% of white and ending with 5% of black
- `background-size` define the size of the gradient : width 100% and height 1.4em (should be the same as `line-height`)
- `background-origin` specifies what the background-position property should be relative to

Comment: Hi I am using px notation and it does not hold against it,  the formatting gets disturbed

Comment: You just have to replace 1.4em with 16px for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position: relative; overflow: hidden;` on topmost `ul` and make separators absolutely positioned

```
.titleSeperator {
    background: black;
    height : 1px;
    width: 10000px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yhvnh/3/

However Lucas proposed better approach, so use it if you can, you should avoid redundant HTML elements.

#### Variant 2

You can also use `:before` pseudo element instead of redundant `.titleSeparator` divs

```
.unstyled > li:before {
    content:'';
    background: black;
    height : 1px;
    width: 10000px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yhvnh/4/